# Why am I unable to connect to MongoDB using NestJS and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a nest.js node server and I am trying to connect mongoDB data base in the app.module, when the connection string doesn't contains the DB name - the connection to default DB "test" success, but when I specify the DB name- always getting "Authentication failed" error.

> [Nest] 53087  - 11/08/2023, 6:30:46 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...

`app.module.ts`:

This works:

```js
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:30000'),
  ]
```

But this specifying the DB name failed with Authentication error:

```js
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:30000/test'),
  ]
```

or:

```
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:30000/data'),
  ]
```

Using MongoClient directly (without nestjs) connecting successfully:

```js
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:30000');
await client.connect();
db = client.db('data');
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify the DB name as a connection option - not as a part of the connection string solved the problem:

```
imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot({
       uri: 'mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:30000',
       dbName: 'data'
    }),
  ]
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [NestJS official document](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb), `forRoot()` method accepts the same configuration object as `mongoose.connect()` from the Mongoose package.

You can see on the documentation of [mongoose.connect()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect), all the options that you can apply.

You may define the db name this way:

```
imports: [
  MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:30000', {
    dbName: 'custom_db_name',
  })
]
```

Answer (score 6):

This actually is not supported on newest version of @nestjs/mongoose, for instance in version ^7.2.4 it receives an string as first parameter and an object as second parameter, so what worked for me was:

```
   imports: [
      MongooseModule.forRoot(
      'mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/nestjs-tutorial?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary',
    ),
    customModule,
   ],
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@Dickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108315/4307534) pointed out, I tried to specify a database, but it didn't help until I checked the `mongoose.connect()` from the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).
So here is the working code for me:

```js
 imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', {
      dbName: 'some_database',
    }),
  ],
```

As same as:

```js
  MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/some_database')
```

As the documentation says:

> This is the minimum needed to connect the myapp database running locally on the default port (27017). If connecting fails on your machine, try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

What I needed was to rename localhost to the IP as [@Ganesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76100815/4307534) tried to mention in his answer.

Comment: Changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, My nest js app stopped working and the error was "can't connect to the database"
After struggling for hours, I changed the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and everything started working.

Old code  `MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/some_database')`

New Code  `MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/some_database')`

I still don't understand why it happened and how `127.0.0.1` is different from `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue after connecting MongooseModule in nest js until I changed my connection string **mongodb://http://localhost:27017/task-prectice** to **mongodb://localhost:27017/task-prectice** or you can replace localhost with **127.0.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `MongooseModule` was masking another underlying error which I only got when I reproduced the issue with just Mongoose on its own:

> MongoAPIError: URI cannot contain options with no value

This pointed me to finding that my `appName` option had no value set (though it applies to any option) - **make sure that all of your options actually have values** or you'll also face:

> ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
>
> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Connection timeout

---

Not working:

```
> mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017?appName=&directConnection=true...
```

Working:

```
mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017?appName=xxx&directConnection=true...
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', { dbName: 'myapp' })
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message "Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)..." in windows from Mongoose in a NestJS application indicates that there is an issue establishing a connection to your MongoDB database. Here are several steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. **Open Services:**
   Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.   Type
   services.msc and press Enter. This will open the Services
   application.
2. **Locate MongoDB Service:**

   ```
       In the Services window, locate the MongoDB service. It may be listed as   "MongoDB" or "MongoDB Server."
   ```
3. **Check Startup Type:**

   ```
       Right-click on the MongoDB service and select "Properties."
       In the Properties window, under the "General" tab, find the "Startup type" dropdown.
       Set the "Startup type" to "Automatic."
   ```
4. **Start the Service:**

   ```
       If the service is not already running, you can start it by clicking the "Start" button in the Properties window.
   ```
5. Apply and OK:

   ```
       Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.
   ```

[image]